# Issues with Linux disk space. Unable to mount 208gb volume?

Tags: linux

So I was installing package updates and stepped away from a while, it apparently installed far more then I was expecting and now it says the disk space is full.  I'm confused by a few things, firstly my disk space should be 813GB and yet under Devices it only shows 208 GB volume, also when I go to open it I get"unable to mount 208 GB volume".  Also I deleted a giant file which should have fixed the issue but it didn't.  Perhaps these screenshots below will help.  I'm contemplating just wiping the drive and installing a fresh version but I would like to understand the issue here in case in happens again.  Note, I am running Parrot if that matters.  Any ideas here?

[image]

Output of fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SPCC M.2 PCIe SSD                       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DDBC0C50-A018-4723-9ACD-4B3BEC283E76

Device               Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1        2048     923647     921600   450M Windows recovery environ
/dev/nvme0n1p2      923648    1126399     202752    99M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3     1126400    1159167      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4     1159168    2158591     999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5     2158592 1589741567 1587582976   757G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6  1589741568 1589743615       2048     1M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7  1589743616 1590794239    1050624   513M Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p8  1590794240 1997340671  406546432 193.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p9  1997340672 1999341567    2000896   977M Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p10 1999341568 2000406527    1064960   520M Windows recovery environ
GPT PMBR size mismatch (4294967294 != 7814037166) will be corrected by write.


Disk /dev/sda: 3.64 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Disk model: BUP Portable    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F8FF62DA-41E9-4E47-8DF4-CFFA71980E66

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      40     409639     409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sda2  411648 7814035455 7813623808  3.6T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/loop0: 55.51 MiB, 58204160 bytes, 113680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 111.59 MiB, 117014528 bytes, 228544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 528.62 MiB, 554299392 bytes, 1082616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 528.18 MiB, 553840640 bytes, 1081720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 110.61 MiB, 115986432 bytes, 226536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 55.52 MiB, 58212352 bytes, 113696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Output of df -Th

```
    df: /run/user/1000/doc: Operation not permitted
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.2G  1.7M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5 btrfs     758G   26G  730G   4% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      16G   59M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p4 ext4      463M  436M     0 100% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p2 vfat       95M   34M   62M  35% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop1     squashfs  112M  112M     0 100% /snap/core/12941
/dev/loop2     squashfs  529M  529M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/267
/dev/loop3     squashfs  529M  529M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/274
/dev/loop4     squashfs  111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12834
/dev/loop5     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.2G   84K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda2      exfat     3.7T  556G  3.1T  15% /media/admin-acc/Backup Plus
```

Comment: Screenshots almost never help because GUI programs tend to hide essential information.   Please add the output of `fdisk -l` for the **relevant** devices (drives and/or partitions) & and `df -Th`  for the relevant mount-points.   Copy and paste the output **text** itself into your question, do not post a screenshot of text.  See [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) for reasons why screenshots of text are worse than useless.

Comment: Thank you.  I just uploaded those.

Comment: Separately you need to fix this: :GPT PMBR size mismatch: repair gpt:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html
More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802
 Most desktops do not need a separate /boot partition. Do not know Parrot and btrfs, so you may need the ext4 just for booting. Windows may need fast start up turned off to allow you to mount the NTFS partition in Linux. Fast start up sets hibernation flag.

Comment: Thank you.  I re-ran the fdisk -l command and it doesn't show the GPT PMBR mismatch anymore.  I did run gdisk and it didn't automatically find anything but the issue was gone after I re-ran that command.  strange.

Comment: the easiest fix would be to move the files in `/boot` (`/dev/nvme0n1p4`), but **NOT** `/boot/EFI` (`/dev/nvme0n1p2`) to your root filesystem (`/`, which is mounted from `/dev/nvme0n1p5`).  A 500MB /boot **should** be enough for grub and a few kernels, but you seem to have installed other stuff into /boot too....and without knowing what you installed or how/why you did that, it's non-viable to suggest ways to clean up the mess. So reorganise things so that /boot is just a subdir of / rather than a separate partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the full `/boot` which is on separate partition so freeing space in your `/home` isn't going to help. 460 MiB for `/boot` isn't that much, I would generally recommend 1 GiB, but you should still be able to free some space in `/boot` and make things work.

You need to [uninstall old kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu). It's usually recommended to keep at least one old kernel after an update and you should be able to fit two kernels in your `/boot` and uninstall all older than that, `apt autoremove` should do that.

You can also try shrinking your btrfs volume and growing the `/boot` partition from a LiveCD, but that would be slow and potentially dangerous (you'd need to move your `/` btrfs volume to the right to make free space for `/boot` which requires copying all the data).

The 208 GB volume is your Windows partition.